# Can a browser extension read the DOM of a web page without opening it in a tab?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a browser-based API(s) can load/read the DOM of a web page without opening it in a tab?

Giving the fact that Chrome extensions can make cross-origin XMLHttpRequest, can I make use of this for reading the DOM of other web pages without opening them in tabs?

Comment: [DOMParser](http://devdocs.io/dom/domparser) API.

Answer (score 2):

This works in firefox.. haven't tried in chrome:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = () => {
    let doc = xhr.responseXML;
    //todo...
}
xhr.onerror = () => console.error('error');
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send();
```

This gives you a document, which can be used like a normal javascript document.

**Edit:**
Keep in mind, that some webpages create or modify the dom using javascript. The above code will only give you the dom from the raw HTML as if no javascript was run on it!

Answer (score 1):

The background *page* of a webextension is a webpage, which can contain iframes. So you should be able to load the page in question into that frame and instrument it with a content script without opening a tab.